# CopyHere method

Tags: powershell, methods

I'm using:

```
$source = "C:\path1"
$destination = "C:\path2"

$FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = "&H0&"
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$objFolder = $objShell.NameSpace($destination)
$objFolder.CopyHere($source, $FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG)
```

This is really nice since it copies files with the native Windows dialog for progress. However, if the files exist, it prompts for a confirmation.

How do I make it overwrite all files?

Reading this, it seems the flag is "16" for yes to all?

Not sure how to integrate it, I'm trying:

```
$objFolder.CopyHere($source, "16")
```

but it doesn't work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/folder-copyhere

Comment: `$objFolder.CopyHere($source,16)` should work. It should be a number and not a string.

Comment: Hi mate, did you get a solution for this? `$objFolder.CopyHere($source,16)` doesn't work for me either. If the target file exists, I still get prompt for overwriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up doing a re-write from some code I found, here is the final working version, progress bar shows but with no prompt stopying to copy if files exist already:

```
$source = "C:\path1"
$destination = "C:\path2"

$SourceNameSpace = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($source)
$destinationFolder = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($destination)
$destinationFolder.CopyHere($source,16)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quotes cause PowerShell to automatically type their contents as a string. Simply use the numbers in that dialog and it should work properly.

This is because shell.application.CopyHere() method uses a bitmask to determine options. It's programmatically more efficient to compare binary registers against each other.

`Try $objFolder.CopyHere( $source, 16 )`

Comment: $objFolder.CopyHere($source, 16) doesn't work, it triggers the copy properly without error however it doesn't overwrite and still prompts for what should be done with existing files.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this at the end

```
set oWShell = createobject("wscript.shell")
do until oWShell.AppActivate("Confirm File Replace")
   Wscript.Sleep 100
loop

oWShell.Sendkeys "{enter}"
```

it will automatically press enter to the prompts