# Why no commandline/powershell command can copy a snapshot image of a open PST file, yet File explorer copy can?

Tags: windows, powershell, outlook, snapshot, robocopy

I am trying to automate some backing up of important stuff in a computer, specifically I want to automate backing up local Outlook archives (`.pst`). The thing is that these computer's users might be using the computer (and thus, outlook and the pst files that Outlook reads/writes to) at the same time.
I figured that the "easy enough" fix was to automate a VSS copy, and then copy the file in the Shadow Copy. I tested it, but it didn't work! paradoxically, it seemed to work just fine if I copied the file BY HAND, in file explorer, but if I try to use `xcopy`, `robocopy` or `copy-Item`, it throws an error.

I can't manage to avoid the problem of "you can't copy a file that's being acessed"... Not even by using a VSS!

This is a code I managed to put together that creates a Volume Shadow copy, copies the file from the shadow copy and deletes the shadow copy afterwards:

```
#Data
$SourceDir=$env:USERPROFILE+'\Documents\Outlook Files' #Location of PST files
$TargetDir='\\NetworkLocation\Resource\Folder'
$logFile='"'+$SourceDir+'\Outlook-backup.log"'

if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $SourceDir)){
    throw "Source: `"$SourceDir`" does not exist"
}
if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $TargetDir)){
    throw "Target: `"$SourceDir`" does not exist"
}

$SourceDir = Get-Item -LiteralPath $SourceDir
$TargetDir = Get-Item -LiteralPath $TargetDir

#Create Volume Shadow Copy
$s1 = (Get-WmiObject -List Win32_ShadowCopy).Create("C:\\", "ClientAccessible")
try{
    $s2 = Get-WmiObject Win32_ShadowCopy | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq $s1.ShadowID }
    $d  = $s2.DeviceObject + "\\"

    #Create symlink to the snapshot for easy access
    cmd /c mklink /d C:\shadowcopy "$d"

    #Find file location inside snapshot
    $null=$SourceDir.FullName -match "(?<=^[a-z]:\\).*$"
    $ShadowSource = "C:\shadowcopy\"+$Matches[0]
    if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $ShadowSource)){
        throw "Shadow source: `"$ShadowSource`" does not exist"
    }
    $ShadowSource = $ShadowSource | Get-Item

    #Copy file from snapshot
    robocopy.exe $ShadowSource.FullName $TargetDir.fullname /MIR /COPY:DAT /J /Z /COMPRESS /R:3 /W:5 /NP /UNILOG:$logFile #/L
    #ROBOCOPY FAILS TO COPY THE FILES
}
catch{
    Write-Host "Error occurred $($_.ScriptStackTrace)"
    Write-Host $_
}
finally{
    #Delete snapshot (In two different ways just in case)
    "vssadmin delete shadows /Shadow=""$($s1.ShadowID.ToLower())"" /Quiet" | iex
    "vssadmin delete shadows /Shadow=""$($s2.ID.ToLower())"" /Quiet" | iex
    #Delete Junction
    cmd.exe /c "rmdir C:\shadowcopy\ & exit"
}
```

The error logged by robocopy for every PST file is:

```
ERROR 33 (0x00000021) [...]The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.
```

How is this possible? Aren't Snapshots supposed to be read-only? Why does it work fine when doint it by hand in file explorer?

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but if copying works using Explorer, I would try [shell API for copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56493639/7571258) (it is the same API internally used by Explorer).